# MATLAB: Is it possible to generate multiple spheres and save them as objects in one script file?

Tags: arrays, matlab, object

As I stated, I am working on an assigment at school and I am pretty stuck at one part.

It is an assigment where I am suposed to generate several spheres andput them through different movment like random acceleration to gravitational pull towards eachother. I know the physics pretty well and can code that part without doubt.

What I am struggling to do though is to save the different spheres as seperate objects. I want to to this so I can simply apply the forces to each object.

One requirement in the assignment is that it has to be in one script file. So I can only use embedded functions (if needed)

EDIT: (Copypaste from comments, with minor clarifying edits)

I did this another way. I Initialized objects with spherical data. Using for loops basically using various loopsetups and nested nested setups similar to  this;

```
value=rand()
for ii =1:n 
objKLOT(1,ii)=struct(’varName1’,value,’varName2’,value,’varName3’,value);
for ii =1:n (Loop_content1=ii (for jj =1:n (Loop_content2=jj) ) Loop content1=Loop_content1 + Loop_content2);
```

Values like mass, density, random init.accel., vectors etc. were set and then I calcuated the volume and the radius of each sphere from the mass and density. After applying initial_acc. I tried to simplify n-body attraction by each sphere having a resultant vector using vect.addition from all forces stemming from Sphere(i) to all other Spheres. Basically for j= i:n F= G * m(i) * m(j) / (r^2) The forcevectors is a must to be able to solve the resultant force using vector addition.The distance r is calculated with this relation r=||vecm(j) - vecm(i)||

Comment: There are several problems you should focus on, of which the spheres are the last. First, treat them as a point-mass and see that you can compute the movement of the CM with respect to one another. After those are known, it's a matter of creating "sphere-looking" objects and animate them according to the points you found in the previous step. Try this approach. If you're still stuck, please provide much more details regarding where **specifically** you're stuck at. Good questions usually ask about isolated and well-defined problems. See also: [ask].

Comment: I did this another way. I Initialized objects with spherical data.Mass, density, random init.accel. vectors.
I calcuated the vol. and the radius of each sphere from the mass and density.
After applying initial_acc. I tried to simplify n-body attraction by each sphere having a resultant vector using vect.addition from all forces stemming from Sphere(i) to all other Spheres.

Basically for  j= i:n F= G *  m(i) * m(j) / (r^2)
The forcevectors is a must to be able to solve the resultant force using vector addition.The distance r is calculated with this relation  r=||vecm(j) - vecm(i)||